# Connecting two servers over internet

Tags: networking, dedicated-server

So I have a dedicated server . Now I need to add another server, but they do not support LAN connections between their servers ( yeah, cheap I know ). So, I need a reliable way to tunnel the two servers as if they were in LAN over the internet, they will be located in the same datacenter.

OS is Windows Server 2008 Web Edition.

Also, I need really low latency not hardcore over the top encryption.

Thanks.

Comment: OS information would be a help. You could use a vpn technology like OpenVPN

Comment: LAN will be cheaper than adding routers and likley faster.  Why not a direct wired link if in same data center?

Comment: Because these are cheap boxes and in the datacenter they do not make modifications to these machines and they do not have a second LAN gigabit port. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenVPN is perfect for this. As far as setup work goes, it'll take a bit of research and futzing around to get working if you're not familiar with the technology. Once set up, though, either should be completely hands off.

Comment: No, it's not Linux.

Comment: Vladimir, OpenVPN is available on Windows and is easy to get running.  If it's a simple topology, you can use the shared secret configuration instead of the public key configuration.  All you have to make sure to do is get port 1194/udp open on the box you're going to designate as the "server".

Comment: Good point, @cjc - I had forgotten that it was available for windows as well.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to install [Unmanaged Hamachi VPN](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/download.aspx) on each machine.  I am talking about the **free stand-alone version** and NOT the web based Hamachi.  Only works on Windows and Mac though.   Also, for this to work, each machine needs outbound connections to the internet enabled (inbound not necessary).